# String input using TextIO

Tags: java, string

I'm new to using Java and I'm trying to make a darts programme. I'm currently having a problem with trying to implement multipliers on the scores.

The way I've set it up is the user is asked for the score, and then a multiplier to the score (single, double or treble) would be entered. This would be read and would alter the initial score accordingly.

I am trying to do this by having the multiplier read using textIO then using an if statement, so for example, if the user entered "double" as their multiplier the score would x2. However the string entry is being skipped over. Sorry for the lengthy question, here is a sample of the current code.

```
int player1Score = 501;
int player2Score = 501;
int roundScore  = 0;
int dartOne   = 0;
int dartTwo = 0;
int dartThree = 0;
String multiplier;


roundScore = dartOne + dartTwo + dartThree;

TextIO.putln ("Player 1: What number are you aiming for? ");
dartOne = TextIO.getInt();
TextIO.putln ("What is your multiplier? ");
multiplier = TextIO.getlnString();
if (multiplier.equals("double")){
    dartOne = dartOne*2;
};
TextIO.putln("You hit " + multiplier + " " + dartOne + " !");
```

I'm currently using an if statement with only the "double" option just to try and get that working before I add on triple and single. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug your program to see what value `multiplier` is getting?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it will just be 'null' until modified, correct? I was hoping the user would enter the value but getlnString(); isn't working, it just prints "What is your multiplier? " but then skips over to the next section (which is not in the sample).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
TextIO.put ("Player 1: What number are you aiming for? ");
dartOne = TextIO.getInt();
TextIO.put ("What is your multiplier? ");
multiplier = TextIO.getlnWord();
if (multiplier.equals("double")){
    dartOne = dartOne*2;
}
TextIO.putln("You hit " + multiplier + " " + dartOne + " !");
```

I've never used `TextIO` before and too lazy to debug it, but this code is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent like 2 and a half hours trawling the internet for a solution and its so simple. Thanks again :)